# Tile and Modify a Numpy Array at the same time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a Numpy array like so:

```
[10, 11, 12]
```

I want to copy it several times to form a new array, but subtract every element by 1 each time I copy, to produce:

```
[[10 11 12]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [ 8  9 10]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 5  6  7]]
```

This is simple with a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
cycles = 6
a = np.array([10, 11, 12])

a = np.stack([a - i for i in range(cycles)])
```

However, I was wondering if there's a Numpy command that does this, or a more efficient way that doesn't use a list comprehension. 
I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
a - np.arange(6)[:,None]
```

Sample run -

```
In [94]: a
Out[94]: array([10, 11, 12])

In [95]: a - np.arange(6)[:,None]
Out[95]: 
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 8,  9, 10],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 5,  6,  7]])
```

Comment: I think Approach #2 is incorrect. Make your test array `a = np.array([10, 1111, 112])`. Then `sub1_rows(a, cycles = 10000)` will return `array([[   10,  1111,   112], [    9,    10,  1111], [    8,     9,    10], ... ])`

Comment: @AGNGazer Ah yes, that won't work for a generic input array that's not necessarily in sequence. Thanks for pointing it out! Removed that one.